# Strange error probably UTF related

Tags: osx, unicode

I am using Emacs 23 under Mac OS X. When I open certain files I get the following error when I try to save them:

```
Warning: ns-convert-utf8-nfd-to-nfc unsupported under GNUstep.

insert-file-contents: Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p, nil
```

Sometimes the opening of new files fails with the same message. When I retry opening them, it works. I have no idea how to fix this. In general unicode works fine.

Comment: Start by making sure it's not your personal configuration that's causing the issue: Launch Emacs via `emacs -Q` and try to reproduce the behavior. If you can't, this means that the issue is related to your personal config. Report back with the results you get.

Comment: The public version of Emacs is now at 24, so consider upgrading.

Comment: `(setq debug-on-error t)` will give you a backtrace when the error is raised. That will give you some more info about what's going on - what function is expecting a char or string and received `nil` instead, etc.